# Can I save all values assigned to one variable each time it loops using python?

Tags: python, loops, variables, pysnmp

i have the following code that does snmp get which works fine but when i try to pull all serial numbers on a device(wlc) using the interface number loop 't' it works well with the print function but when it saves it into the variable vaBinds[3][1] it only saves the last one. how can i save all the variable values each time it loops.

not sure if my question makes sense but please assist in anyway possible. thank you in advance.

```
        for t in range(1, 3):
            t = str(t)
            t.strip()

            errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
                getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                       CommunityData(item, mpModel=0 or 1),
                       UdpTransportTarget((str(i), 161), timeout=0, retries=0),
                       ContextData(),
                       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0)),  # 0
                       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysLocation', 0)),  # 1
                       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysContact', 0)),  # 2
                       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('ENTITY-MIB', 'entPhysicalSerialNum', t)),  # 3
                       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('ENTITY-MIB', 'entPhysicalModelName', t))),  # 4

            )
            # print(varBinds[3][1])

            if errorIndication:
                print(errorIndication)
            elif errorStatus:
                print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(i),
                                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))  # error exceptions

            else:
                for varBind in varBinds:
                    B = varBinds[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (your account seems new). Small advice, you should reduce your code to a minimal reproducible problem. When you just put your full code here, it feels like it is upon the reader to break down the problem for you.

Comment: AsTeR is right, always try to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, you are referencing a value that's residing somewhere in a mutable container data structure. Being mutable it mutates on every call.

If that's the case, perhaps you could instead reference the scalar (immutable) values on every iteration:

```
 my_values = []

 for t in range(1, 3):
     # perform SNMP GET
     ...
     my_values.extend((vb[0], vb[1]) for vb in var_binds)
```